# gfortran compiler flag for strict Fortran 77 compliance

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

Is there any way to get gfortran to reject the Fortran 95 additions to Fortran 77?

I've tried using the `-std=legacy` flag but that only seems to remove deprecation warnings from f77 programs; the f95 enhancements still work fine.

Comment: For gfortran, `gnu` and `legacy` are supposed to be a superset of Fortran 95.  The options under `-std` are from 95 and onward (see manual).  Why do you want to restrict yourself to FORTRAN 77?

Comment: @M.S.B. there are a few reasons; i'm working with lots of f77 libraries in legacy contexts and i just kind of want everything to be consistent...it just feels better in my head.

Comment: Perhaps it is an obvious answer, but if you want to force yourself to using F77, why don't you just not use the F90+ additions in your code?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm trying that, but I am sure that sometimes they slip through when I look at blog posts and stuff for help.  Also I'm going to be back-converting a few programs as well and sometimes I'm not sure which parts are enhancements and which parts aren't sometimes.

Comment: Why not just try g77 instead of gfortran.  That way, you don't have to worry about later versions.

Comment: g77 is way too obsolete and unmaintained. You may try Oracle Studio which can bee called as `f77` (which is just a wrapper to `f95` with some options).

Comment: I do not see any good reason to keep f77 compatibility outside niche platforms like IBM VS Fortran for mainframes. In particular note that many so called FORTRAN 77 programs do not keep the standard and contain many proprietary extensions which are likely to remain undetected by potential validation tools.

Comment: Better than relying on a compiler, there are the free [ftnchek](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/ftnchek/) and the commercial [forcheck](http://www.forcheck.nl/), that do exactly what you want: check standard conformance.

Answer (score 0):

I would have also tried it with a couple of gfortran compiler flags.

If you are flexible with additional libraries there is another Fortran 77 compiler besides f77.
It is called cf77 from Concurrent. It is a compiler including some real time libraries. Here you can find the [Documentation](https://www.concurrent-rt.com/customer-support/)

As I remember there is still a license fee. But this compiler supports pure f77 and still has the old libraries included.

Another option could be using the g77 compiler and eventually downgrading your available libraries. Here is a [Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g77) for the g77 compiler.

Comment: g77 actually supports many non-standard extensions and even some Fortran 90 features. But with some specific flags (perhaps `-pedantic`) it might be stricter.

Answer (score -1):

You can set fixed format with

```
gfortran -ffixed-form -ffixed-line-length-none [sourcefiles]
```

And this can actually make a difference (I have a program here where this changes the output!).

I’m pretty sure that there are options, which disable at least most of the f95 features.

Comment: Fixed format does not really make any difference. Fixed format is perfectly legal (even if obsolete) in Fortran 2018.

Comment: What do you mean by "really"? AFAIK it is legal, but it can be interpreted differently by modern standards (because that’s what I got in one project). But don’t take my word for it, try it out. I did hit a project where it made a difference, but this was a long time ago and I have not written any Fortran for the past 3 years, so I’m far enough out of the loop that I can no longer doublecheck this.

Comment: No, the source form cannot make a difference in the output unless you have lines that are too long for fixed output and have them truncated in some unfortunate way. But then the `-ffixed-form` would brake it, not fix it! Also, you would have to have the file named `.f90` for the option to do anything at all. The option will not do anything to `.f` or `.for` files.

Comment: As far as I understand it when looking back into compiler documentation, `-ffixed-form` together with `-ffixed-line-length-none` switches to fixed form while allowing long lines. I cannot check anymore what the suffixes were, so free-form assumption due to misnamed files might have been the reason.