# gfortran: Force static memory allocation

Tags: memory, static, fortran, allocation, gfortran

I'm currently updating some old F77 fixed format code and compiling with gfortan.

Is there a way to obtain a warning when I do *not* use static memory allocation, e.g. if I call a subroutine and pass some dimension value that is not fixed at runtime?

Or would I have to use old f77 compilers?

EDIT:

Here is some code example:

```
      program test

        integer A,b
        read(*,*) b

        select case(b)
          case(50)
            A=40
          case(40)
            A = 50
        end select

        call arr(A)
      end

      subroutine arr(A)
        integer A
        double precision E(A,A)

        E(1,1) =10.
        E(42,41)= 41
        write(*,*)  E(42,41), A
      end
```

Comment: Not many people need this, so it will be difficult to find it. Do you have some computer from the 60s?

Comment: See the comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004270/strict-fortran77-compiler-or-gfortran-compiler-flag

Comment: can you show an example of code you want to catch

Comment: If not static are you using `allocatable` or `pointers`?

Comment: Here is some code example:
          program test
          integer A,b
          read(*,*) b
          select case(b)
          case(50)
          A=40
          case(40)
          A = 50
          end select
          call arr(A)
          end
          subroutine arr(A)
          integer A
          double precision E(A,A)
          E(1,1) =10.
          E(42,41)= 41
          write(*,*)  E(42,41), A
          end

I'm using the old F77 style so this corresponds to the F90-automatic arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `select case`, which is Fortran 90. Therefore, using a Fortran 77 compiler is not an option. I am worried that you just have to be careful. If you stay away from `allocatable`, `pointer` and `allocate`, you just have to be sure that there are no automatic arrays. You can also disable stack allocation for small static arrays and other variables by `-fno-automatic` or similar.

Regarding your example, it indeed uses an automatic array. If you REALLY need to stay away from them, you have to declare the bounds as compile-time constants:

```
  subroutine arr(A)
    integer MAXA
    parameter (MAXA=1000)
    integer A
    double precision E(MAXA,MAXA)

    E(1,1) =10.
    E(42,41)= 41
    write(*,*)  E(42,41), A
  end
```

Comment: okay. This would be a solution. But: My point is that like this you put the information into the code I'd like to have checked. f77 compilers would just throw an error.
However, this means I just have to be more careful.